# Hi-Res OS X interface PSDs

Tags: macos, user-interface, transparency

I'm looking for really hi-res, perhaps vector, images of all the Mac OS X interface elements... particularly the black translucent 'pro' style. For marketing mockups.. I'm surprised I can't find a source. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check items in this list, some are Omni Graffle templates which are not edittable outside but others are illustrator files..

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/05/50-free-ui-and-web-design-wireframing-kits-resources-and-source-files/

hope it works.

Comment: In my experience OmniGraffle is terrible for prototyping.  Stretched images do not look good.

Comment: i use fireworks and keynote for prototyping. OmniGraffle is too narrow minded for me.